# How to target specific solutions in a TFS team build definition using WF?

Tags: tfs, workflow, build-process

Here is my situation.

I setup a build definition for continuous integration using the new workflow system. Then I targeted this definition to a particular solution. I checked-in my solution many times without a problem and the builds have all passed flawlessly on the server.

This morning, I notice that it has been executed but I did not checked-in the solution. I finally discover that when a colleague checked-in another solution, it executed the definition for the solution I am working on.

I am using the original ProcessTemplate.xaml file. I only want this build definition to be executed when I check-in a particular solution or a set of solution I chose. What do I miss here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to do,
1. Edit build defination and click on the process tab, change the 'Items to Build' to the solution that you are interested to be build as part of your build.
2. Click on the workspace tab and point it only to the branch or specifically to the folder which logically excludes the solutions that you would like to exlude from this ci build.

[image]

Make sure you carry these steps across your build definations.

HTH.
Cheers, Tarun

Comment: Thank you. I had only one working folder set on the team project root.